# How much actual coding is necessary for implementing header bidding with Prebid.js?

Tags: header-bidding

How much actual coding is necessary for implementing header bidding?
I want to implement a header bidding solution for a website (as a publisher), specifically using Prebid.js. I am trying to establish how much of my own new coding will it necessitate or will I only need to use the code given by Prebid and implement it on my website.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are three parts to prebid:

- the Prebid library
- the Prebid API / GAM API
- the GAM line items

The first part can be easily downloaded and contains all of the guys for how prebid works. You don’t need to change a thing here and the prebid.org site makes this really easy to get.

The API calls however are specific to your publisher, the settings for each SSP (bidder parameters), and how your GAM is setup on page.

Assuming you have a simple setup, you should be able to get running with the examples in the getting started guides.

GAM line item setup can be a chore to do manually so I would recommend creating a script to do this or reach out to your SSP parters to do this on your behalf.

Disclaimer: I work at Xandr